# IIS take an Hour to serve new Files

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, server, web-config

I have an ASP.NET webforms application online. I usually upload my changes via FTP copy of the bin files and the changed asp files. Nowadays I have noticed that everytime i replace the bin folder, IIS takes around an hour to serve the new pages. However this was not the case two weeks back. As soon as I replace the bin folder, IIS restarts and new pages are served.

Could this be the issue with the hosting providers server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something caching the pages, To help find out where the issue could be, You should try accessing the updated pages on a new PC, preferably one on a separate network that has never accessed the site before.

If you see the same delays on a new pc on a separate network then it is probably the providers configurations. If the site loads fine on a separate PC and network then it could be a local issue, some corporate systems can do caching to limit internet costs for the network your on or it might just be your browser cache.

Comment: I Tried that. When I logged in from another computer. It shows the new Page and when I log in from my computer, it shows the old page. I did try clearing the cache. That did not help. Do you know why this is happening ?

Comment: Did you try `ctrl+F5` also if you clear your cache with the browser running it can have some files locked open and fail to remove them. Typically `ctrl+F5` tells the browser to force a full refresh. You can also use google chromes incognito mode since it doesn't use the same cache.

Comment: I Did try the private browsing. It still shows the old page in my Machine. Whereas the PC on different network shows the updated version of the website. I am still wondering How this is possible. I did try clearing the cache. Did not help

Comment: In that case there might be a networking device or a proxy server on your local network that is caching the page for you. If you have one, speak to your IT department and ask them if this is the case. To further confirm its not your computer, Try another that is on the same network. If it is the same issue on another PC on the SAME network then its not your PC. If its fine on the other PC then its some very weird computer issue it seems.

Comment: I used my mobile network tethering to connect to the internet from my PC and the webpage shows the new version. Thanks a lot Nick. You helped me identify the issue. You are awesome.